# load an OCX dynamically and get the handle of loaded module in C#

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

I am going to load an OCX in runtime and pass the handle of loaded ocx to another function which is a patch ,
I have the delphi code and it works fine , I want to convert it to c# but I don't know how

```
Type    
  TDLLFunc = procedure(param1: dword);
VAR
  DLLFunc      : TDLLFunc;
  OcxDllHndle  : LongInt;
  DllHandle    : LongInt;

begin
  OcxDllHndle := LoadLibrary('SampleOcx.Dll');
  DllHandle   := LoadLibrary('Patch.dll');
  @DLLFunc    := GetProcAddress(DllHandle, 'DoPatch');
  DLLFunc(OcxDllHndle);
end;
```

here is the c# code but it doesnt work (I made AxInterop version of OCX ) :

```
AppDomain Domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TestApp", null, null);
var assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(@".\AxInterop.SampleOcx.dll");
Assembly Ocx = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
IntPtr DLLHandle = LoadLibrary(Application.StartupPath + @"\Patch.dll");
IntPtr funcaddr = GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, "DoPatch");

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
delegate void MyFunc(int Handle);

MyFunc DLLFunc = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(funcaddr, typeof(MyFunc)) as    MyFunc;
IntPtr OCXHandle = Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Ocx.GetType().Module);
DLLFunc(OCXHandle.ToInt32());
```

Please help

Comment: You don't do any error checking. How can you tell it fails? Next step is to check for errors. Read the docs for the API calls you make to find out how. I also wonder why you would call LoadLibrary. Just pinvoke it directly and let the framework load the library.

Comment: Thank you David , Actually I check it in the lines below which i didn't mention it in the code sample , when the patch works , the subsequent calls to ocx functions will return proper values , and in the above sample ocx functions do not return proper value.

Answer (score 0):

The function that is exported from that Delphi DLL cannot be called from C#. The Delphi DLL exports the function using the `register` calling convention which is a non-standard Delphi only calling convention. You will need to modify the DLL to export using, for instance, `stdcall`.

Assuming you made the change the C# code would look like this:

```
[DllImport("patch.dll")]
static extern void DoPatch(IntPtr moduleHandle);
....
IntPtr OcxHandle = LoadLibrary("SampleOcx.dll");
if (OcxHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    .... handle error
DoPatch(OcxHandle);
```

Note that the parameter is not really a `DWORD`. It is an `HMODULE`. That's a 64 bit type under 64 bit process. Which leads me to point out that your program must target x86 to work with your 32 bit Delphi DLL. And the OCX is presumably 32 bits too.

Comment: I see , but how then I get an Instance of the ocx , after calling LoadLibrary ?

Comment: My code demonstrates that. The value returned by LoadLibrary is the instance. The C# code is identical to the Delphi code.